# Ruby - stop program from executing in certain way

Tags: ruby

I wrote a parser, which recognizes elements of text based on certain pattern.
My program is able to recognize paragraph, chapter etc. The problem is it shouldn't recognize elements, when there's a quote. For example:

```
Paragraph 1
Something here...
```

would be proceed as Paragraph.
And:

```
  Paragraph 1
  "Paragraph 2"
```

shouldn't. But as my program is based on regexp patterns, it looks for the word "Paragraph". I'm going line by line and recognize patterns for each line. I don't know how to tell my program: if you see quotes mark, leave text alone without doing anything? My mentor told me to use raise, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: What have you tries so far? Please include your code in the post, including its output/any errors.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ the advice to use `raise` here is uhmmm... a bit strange. Regexp for the word, _not preceeding by a quote_ is: `/(?<!")Paragraph/`.

Comment: How can we help you improve your current implementation if you don't show it to us?

Comment: My parser is a big project, there are many files cooperating together. Every line is checked for many different Regexps. If line is empty, I use next if line.empty?. I wanted to use if line.quote; raise;end, but it stops the whole thing

Comment: The usual pattern in Ruby when iterating and processing elements is `each` on the elements involved, but I don't see any code here. This sample data is also pretty thin. Normally documents of this sort have so-called smart-quotes in them like `“Sample text”` and things like `“Gadzooks,” exclaimed the mad scientist.` where the very idea of what's quoted is sometimes subtle.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I'm still a bit of a beginner, I don't know if there is a way to direct the regex to ignore things inside quotes, but if I wanted to solve this problem, I would first make a copy of the text to be parsed, run a regex over that and delete everything inside quotes, then run the parser over the remaining text.

A bit kludgy and inelegant I admit, and may have performance issues over a large enough text, but it would get the job done.

See [HERE](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html) for link to documentation of ruby regex. About a third of the way down it discusses quotes:

/\p{Pi}/ - 'Punctuation: Initial Quote'

/\p{Pf}/ - 'Punctuation: Final Quote'

You may be able to bake that into the regex with the ^ to direct it to ignore items in quotes.

Comment: I'm not sure what this answers, if it answers anything at all. Also, when linking to documentation try and link to the current version whenever possible, which is now 2.3.3.